# Formula field not working! Strange!

Tags: formula, custom-field, custom

I have created fromula field on opportunity and wanted to get true if following conditions are met. Still its not getting true.

```
IF((TEXT(Account.Type)== "Test" ) && CONTAINS( Account.Name , "Test") , true, false)
```

Not getting what i am missing. also, checked text (Test) its same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks ok at a cursory glance. As such either the Opp is not related to the Account you think it is or the values are not as you expect. Did you really add a picklist value of Test to the standard Type field on the account?

Comment: this won't fix the issue, but you don't need the if - it's condition is a boolean and you return a boolean, so just return "(TEXT(Account.Type)== "Test" ) && CONTAINS( Account.Name , "Test")". Could the double = be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If the result is not what you expect, some of the conditions is not what you think it is. You can manually check each condition by looking at the related records, or temporarily break the formula into parts, for example make it `IF(TEXT(Account.Type) =="Test"), true, false)` and see if that works then check the other condition to see what part is true or not. This is helpful for more complex formulas in my opinion, this one is quite simple.

Oh, and I'm almost sure CONTAINS is case sensitive, check if the Account Name really contains "Test" in its name. That can be your mistake.